# Is there a way to share the same .NET 1.1 web.config file accross IIS5 and IIS7

Tags: .net, iis, windows-xp, web-config, windows-vista

I am using Vista, but most of the other developers working on the same projects as me are still using XP. Some of our projects have wildcard script mappings for handling vanity URLs, so each time I work on those sites, my IIS 7 adds a **system.webServer/handlers** section to the web.config file and when one of the other developers do an update it is not recognised by their IIS 5 systems and results in the following error:

```
Parser Error Message: Unrecognized configuration section 'system.webServer'
```

So is there either an IIS 7 setting for it to not store script mappings in the web.config file, or a way of telling IIS 5 to ignore that section?

I have Googled this, but I only seem to find guides from people migrating from IIS5/6 to 7.

Comment: Are you using source control?

Comment: Yes: SVN, with a tortoise client

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Managed to answer my own question.

We have to modify the machine.config files on the XP machines. And add

```
<section name="system.webServer" type="System.Configuration.IgnoreSectionHandler,
System, Version=1.0.5000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
```

to the `<configSections>` section

That tells .NET on the XP machine to ignore that section.

Comment: THANKS!!!!! This was driving me crazy! I had already my project running and suddenly, this started happening!!!!